# How to run unit tests on TeamCity with multiple agents?

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity with 3 agents, and more that 20 configurations for different branches.
Simultaneously on TeamCity runs multiple builds what use same 2-3 databases for unit tests. But in each  branches this databases has a differences: new table, columns, etc.

In Db project in c# i have `recreate database` option.
And when new build start to run database recreating on SQL Server. Right?  And here is problem i see that alot of test falls with errors what multiple builds running.

How can i run tests for different builds in separate databases?

or maybe i'm wrong and all problem in `.emdx` files what creating on agents?

**Error example**

```
Test(s) failed. System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException : An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

----> System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException : The query view generated for the EntitySet 'DigitalDocuments' is not valid. The query parser threw the following error : The argument type 'Edm.Int32' is not compatible with the property 'IsDeleted' of formal type 'Edm.Boolean'. Near member access expression, line 4, column 109..
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__1()
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0()
   в System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0()
   в System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в MyDataClassesTest.MyUnitTest.Test1() в C:\BuildAgent2\BuildAgent\work\3ba40c5d39eaa66e\MyDataClassesTest\MyUnitTest.cs:строка 36
--MappingException
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView.GetCommandTree()
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView.GetInternalTree(Command targetIqtCommand)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitScalarOpDefault(ScalarOp op, Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.VisitScalarOpDefault(ScalarOp op, Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FunctionOp op, Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo, Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   в System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)

Comment: Seems question not to teamcity, but to your tests. They does not support parallel runs.  Show the full error message to understand limitation. If all tests try to recreate the same db - they will fail. So maybe different tests should work with own db name...

Comment: @daggett I'm not sure that error text helps but i'd added it to question. You probably right and this is parrallel test runs issue. Becouse in each unit test projeect i have a App.config with database connections string so database is hardcoded. But i don't know hwo to fix it.

Comment: Rewrite config with any Lang you know. With powershell for example.

Comment: @daggett Do you mean that i gonna use powershell runner and pass parameters to it? If so can you give example how to pass test db connection string to runner?

Comment: Could you show your config file? Maybe only part with connection.